# Social Login Buttons CSS to change from one by one >>>> one under the other

Tags: css, wordpress

can someone tell me the CSS to change the buttons from:
one by one >>>>> one under the other
like in the screenshot
Webpage: 
[LogIn webpage link](http://www.virtual-forms.com/wp-login.php)

[One under the other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5wpb.png)

Comment: Did you try the solution?

Comment: I missed one css class change. Please try the below solutin. Hope it will works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS

```
    ul.the_champ_login_ul li { width: 100% !important; }
   .theChampLogin { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: it is working, thank you. Now I need to find how to add text to this buttons

Comment: why this doesn't work with the widget, as I can see the names are the same? on this page: http://www.virtual-forms.com/forums/

Answer (score 1):

try using flex

```
.the_champ_login_ul {
   display: flex ; 
   flex-direction : column;
  }
```

Comment: it did put the buttons one under the other but the 100% width is missing, Thank you too for another approach

Comment: i thought you want just to display then one under the other, you can add width : 100% to each li element then it will works :)

Comment: thank GmaSa I need to award someone and Ravi was faster :-(

Comment: maybe you can help me with the next step? The question ishe here: http://www.virtual-forms.com/wp-login.php

Comment: No Problem :) , ps: i cant find your question

Comment: ups sorry here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344576/display-text-from-alt-tag-of-from-title-tag-on-a-button-with-css